Horror movie takes place in enclosed space
I apologize if the details I give are too vague, but they are all I can remember. In the movie a group of people are in some sort of abandoned building (possibly a mall, lab, etc.). As the movie progresses the people in the group begin to get picked off and murdered. The scene that I can remember the best is the remainder of the group finding some sort of control room to watch the surveillance tapes to see what happened to the now dead group members. On the video the group sees one of their current group members murdering the dead group member, but he has no knowledge of ever committing the murder. He claims that it wasn't him and that somebody else did it. I may be wrong  when I say this, but I feel like there was something that could transform into a specific person in the group to cox a member alone and then kill them one by one. Please help me before I go insane!

This is a plot to a Futurama episode - I think the one with the team-building exercise.

It's a not too uncommon plot idea also explored in other series, like one episode of Sanctuary. Do you possibly remember the origin of the movie? Did it have Asian or western people?

I think a lot of Blair Witch 2 takes place in some abandoned factory and involves people watching themselves killing other people in surveillance tapes and not remembering it... But I don't remember much either of that crapfest. :)

It would be helphzul if you could say something more. How were they picked off and such?

As Walt mentioned in the comments, it sounds a lot like Book of Shadows: Blair Witch 2 (2000).
After the group go into the woods to investigate the original Blair Witch location strange and horrible things start happening and they have to go to the hospital:

Later, at the hospital, Tristen sees a ghostly young girl walking away backwards. After she is discharged, Jeff takes the group to his home, an abandoned broom factory in the woods. It has an elaborate security system, including a deep trench and bridge to the entrance, many surveillance cameras, and a front door that plays the sound of barking guard dogs whenever it is opened. They review their tapes and find hours of footage are missing.

While they're there, people start disappearing and acting strangely, and near the end of the film they check the security tapes for the building:

The group sits in the loft trying to make sense of the situation. Tristen suggests everything is backwards. They are confused, but Kim tells Jeff to play the tapes in reverse to view the lost footage. This works, and the new footage shows Tristen leading them in an orgy and the ritualistic murder of the other tour group

And at the end of the film the survivors are arrested and shown more videos:

The group is arrested and interrogated separately. In Kim's room, they play security footage from the store of her stabbing the cashier in the neck with a nail file. In Jeff's video, he kills Erica, arranges Erica's clothes and stows her dead body in the closet. In Stephen's video, they show him lynching Tristen, putting the rope around her neck, accusing her of all the death that surrounds them and cursing her as a witch (as do Kim and Jeff). Then he finally pushes her over the railing. All three claim they never did any of those things. Stephen screams in anger and horror that someone doctored the tape and all of this never happened.


The description matches with Blair Witch 2 as far as I can remember of this movie. Not that bad. Better than the 1st.
